# Exportación de datos SQL Server a otro Servidor

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, script

Compañeros tengo la siguiente consulta, quiero hacer la exportacion de los datos obtenidos mediante este Query, es un resumen de transacciones diarias:

```
 SELECT        otrnTransaction.ID_Trn AS IdDiarioTrans, otrnTransaction.PostingDate AS Fecha, V_Guest.AccountNo AS Folio, 
                         CASE SubFolio WHEN 0 THEN 'A' WHEN 1 THEN 'B' WHEN 2 THEN 'C' WHEN 3 THEN 'D' END AS SubFolio, rmRoom.RoomNo AS Habitacion, otrnTransaction.Reference AS Referencia, 
                         otrnTransaction.ID_TrnCode AS IdTipoTransaccion, CASE TrnFamily WHEN 0 THEN 'Sale' WHEN 1 THEN 'Tax' WHEN 2 THEN 'Accounting' WHEN 3 THEN 'Receipt' END AS TipoTransaccion, 
                         prCode.Name AS ShortName, otrnTransaction.AmountPur + otrnTransaction.AmountCentralRetailMarkup + otrnTransaction.AmountTaxes AS Monto, otrnTransaction.Comment AS Comentario
FROM            otrnTransaction INNER JOIN
                         V_Guest ON otrnTransaction.ID_Account = V_Guest.ID_Account INNER JOIN
                         rmRoom ON otrnTransaction.ID_Room = rmRoom.ID_Room AND V_Guest.ID_Room = rmRoom.ID_Room INNER JOIN
                         prCode ON otrnTransaction.ID_TrnCode = prCode.ID_Code INNER JOIN
                         acTrnCode ON prCode.ID_Code = acTrnCode.ID_TrnCode INNER JOIN
                         acTrnGroup ON acTrnCode.ID_TrnGroup = acTrnGroup.ID_TrnGroup
WHERE        (otrnTransaction.PostingDate = (SELECT CurrentHotelDate FROM prProperty))
```

Siendo el resultado, el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me han solicitado que estos datos sean exportados a otro servidor SQL en la misma red, he leído algo acerca de Vincular los servidores, pero no sabría como hacerlo, cabe resaltar que esta exportación debe hacerse diariamente. me pueden ayudar un poco?

Comment: Alguno de los dos servidores puede ser accedido por internet?

Comment: Ambos servidores pueden ser accedidos por internet

Comment: yo te recomendaría hacer un programita, en el lenguaje que te guste que realice la tarea y después con el programador de tareas de windows lo corres a la hora que quieras los días que quieras. Hacer esto como tarea desde sql server.. nose si se puede

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ello necesitas configurar un `Linked Server`, ésto se realiza desde el `Explorador de Objetos` de `SMSS`, en `Server Objects` (si no me equivoco, se llaman servidores vinculados en la versión en español). Debes hacer click derecho para crear un nuevo Linked Server

[image: Linked Server]

Para ello necesitas la `instancia de la BD del servidor` y `credenciales` para que te puedas conectar a ese servidor.

[image: Linked server configuración básica]